# check in python if a conda package exist

Tags: python, package, conda

For a given python version, platform, is there a way
to check if a package is available on conda (using python),
other than scraping conda website ?

The goal is to check using python code, and not via scraping or
command line scraping.

Example URL :
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xlwt/files

Answer (score 6):

You can search for available packages

`conda search $SEARCH_TERM`

Examples from the [official documentation](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-search.html):

> Search for a specific package named 'scikit-learn':
>
> ```
> conda search scikit-learn
> ```
>
> Search for packages containing 'scikit' in the package name:
>
> ```
> conda search *scikit*
> ```
>
> Note that your shell may expand '*' before handing the command over  to
>   conda.   Therefore  it  is  sometimes necessary to use single or double
>   quotes around the query.
>
> ```
> conda search '*scikit' conda search "*scikit*"
> ```
>
> Search for packages for 64-bit Linux (by  default,  packages  for  your
>   current platform are shown):
>
> ```
> conda search numpy[subdir=linux-64]
> ```
>
> Search for a specific version of a package:
>
> ```
> conda search 'numpy>=1.12'
> ```
>
> Search for a package on a specific channel
>
> ```
>  conda   search   conda-forge::numpy  conda  search  'numpy[chan‐nel=conda-forge, subdir=osx-64]'
> ```

Comment: `subdir=linux-64` for platform name. Not sure what you mean for given python version.. I'm not aware of conda having such a separation between python versions..

Answer (score 0):

What you need is using Python to call the conda command,
so you can use subprocess.run() to do this.

```
import subprocess
check_package = subprocess.run(['conda', 'list', 'your_package_name'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(check_package.stdout)
```

Comment: in conda online repository: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytest/files